# Can Kibana 3 and Kibana 4 Be Used Side-By-Side?

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I'm currently using Kibana 3, and would like to upgrade to Kibana 4. However, I would like to keep Kibana 3 around until I have my dashboards in Kibana 4 configured. Can the two be run side-by-side without interfering with one another?

I know that Kibana stores its settings in the attached Elasticsearch database, so I am worried that Kibana 4 might overwrite settings in my Kibana 3 instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose the name of the index to use in the Kibana settings file (Kibana 4; Don't sure if 3 includes this option).

kibana.yml

```
    # Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches,    visualizations
    # and dashboards. It will create a new index if it doesn't already exist.
    kibana_index: ".kibana"
```

Change it to something like .kibana4

```
    kibana_index: ".kibana4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Kibana 3 & Kibana 4 can work side by side.Just run Kibana 3 & Kibana 4.

Answer (score 0):

There are massive differences in how you work with data and what you can do in Kibana 3 and 4, therefore in many cases you would want to run them both, especially now when there is a version of K3 supporting Elasticsearch 2.X and its aggregations.

https://github.com/immunochomik/kibana3

I think it is good practice to use K3 as a discovery panel, to get at a glance inside into what is going on, but then you need K4 to answer more involved questions. This is because discovery panel in K4 (4.4) is pretty much useless - you can not apply and remove time filters, there is only one query, documents take too much space on the documents panel and you can not easily display values for just one field, finally I need terms aggregations on a discovery panel so I can see how often given event type happens.

Answer (score 0):

I am using both in my app. Kibana 3, I bundle as a war file in Jetty where as Kibana 4 runs as stand alone using Jetty's reverse proxy.

The Kibana 4 strategy is documented here http://tapasadhikary.blogspot.in/2016/04/transitioning-from-elastics-kibana-3x.html

I would probably get rid of K3 version once I am able to migrate my dashboards.